# Передача параметра замыканию (Closure)

Tags: php

При работе с замыканиями встречаю две возможные конструкции:

1. `$closure = function($config){};`
2. `$closure = function() use ($config) {};`

В чем их отличие? В каких случаях использовать первую, а в каких вторую?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала давайте определимся с терминологией. Замыкание - это совокупность функции и контекста в котором она определена, при этом функция может оперировать переменными из этого контекста.

Давайте теперь разбирать ваши примеры по порядку.

```
$f = function($config) {
    // ...
};
```

Это обычная анонимная функция, не являющаяся замыканием, в строгом смысле. Она не может (и не должна) использовать переменные из контекста своего определения. Такие функции полезны, когда результат работы функции полностью зависит от переданных аргументов. (Замечание: если же функция `$f` полностью детерминирована и не содержит побочных эффектов, то можно сказать, что это [чистая функция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).) Типичный пример - отображение массива:

```
array_map(function($item) {
    return $item + 1;
}, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Теперь посмотрим на другой ваш пример:

```
$closure = function() use ($config) {
    // ...
};
```

В этом случае действительно можно говорить о замыкании, поскольку функция `$closure` использует переменную `$config` из контекста, в котором определена. Такие функции полезны, во множестве случаев:

- интерфейс, использующий анонимную функцию заранее определен, но функции нужны дополнительные данные для работы. Вот пример, из взаимодействия с фреймворком Silex:

  ```
  $app = new Silex\Application(); 

  $app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
      // Анонимная функция должна принимать единстенный аргумент $name.
      // Однако для работы ей так же требуется метод $app->escape.
      return 'Hello ' . $app->escape($name); 
  }); 

  $app->run();
  ```
- нужно использовать анонимную функцию, которая должна иметь какие-то побочные эффекты. (Замечание: в данном случае мы можем использовать глобальные переменные, однако это совсем грустный путь (проблемы с тестированием, неочевидность изменения переменной и т.д.).) Для примера, к некой анонимной функции добавим вывод отладочной информации:

  ```
  $logger = new Logger();

  $action = function($target) use ($logger) {
      $logger->debug($target);
      // Делаем какие-то действия с аргументами и возвращаем результат
      return 'result';
  };

  $app->use($action);
  ```
- есть и другие полезные применения замыканий, которые практикуются в функциональном программировании. Тема довольно обширна, поэтому подробно останавливаться не буду, но приведу упрощенный пример реализации [каррирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) на PHP:

  ```
  $curry = function($f, $a) {
      return function($b) use ($f, $a) {
          return $f($a, $b);
      };
  };

  $add = function($a, $b) {
      return $a + $b;
  };

  $add_five = $curry($add, 5);
  var_dump($add_five(7)); // 12
  ```

Comment: Спасибо. Стало яснее.

Answer (score 2):

```
$closure = function($config){};
```

- `$config` имеет любое значение, которое передается как аргумент;

```
$closure = function() use ($config) {};
```

- `$config` - это переменная из области видимости, которая находится над вызовом функции. То есть, как если бы Вы в javascript выполнили:

```
(function(){
 var config = 'config';
 var closure = function() { console.log(config); }
 closure();
})();
```

а в PHP для этого надо указать, что `$config` должен быть доступен "внутри":

```
$config = 'config';
$closure = function() use($config) { var_dump($config); }
$closure();
```

Comment: Если Вы видели мой первый ответ - он был некорректен, поэтому я скрыл его на время редактирования.

Comment: Сравнение с JS это здорово, но не отражает достоинств/недостатков каждого из определений анонимных функций.

Comment: А по-моему, все и так ясно из контекста использования.

Comment: В случае, если мы берем объект из глобальной области видимости и изменяем его внутри замыкания, этот объект меняется и в глобальной области видимости? Отличие ли это от первого случая?

Comment: Объект - да, другой тип - нет. Так же, как и передача в аргументах, конструкция use передает либо копию переменной, либо ссылку на нее - ... use (&$config) ...

Comment: Получается, что отличие исключительно в способе передачи аргумента? т.е. отличий нет? Почему же тогда используют разные варианты?

Comment: @Mik, вот видите, не все ясно из контекста ;)

Comment: @Razzwan, я, к сожалению, не могу сейчас привести достаточно заковыристый пример, но у меня точно была ситуация, когда я не мог просто взять и передать в closure аргумент. Однако, на готове есть банальный ответ: если closure при каждом вызове получает одну и ту же переменную из одной и той же области, есть смысл перенести переменную в use. А передача аргументов - это более универсальный инструмент.